# django adding multiple model image instances using form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want to save 400 picture to my Image model using one single file field and i dont know how tp get each image from the form and create an instance on the Image model

here is my model function:

```
class Image(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and here is my form:

```
class AddImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
image = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','multiple':'true'}))
class Meta:
    model = Image
    fields = ['image']
```

and here is my view which i know is wrong just to make sure i share everything:

```
def imagesform(request):
form = AddImageForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        for i in form['image']:
            Image.objects.create(image=i)


context = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'members/imagesform.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple file uploads can be a pain to implement, but you're almost there! From what I see, the only thing that's missing is that you should instantiate your form with the `request.POST` and `request.FILES` arguments:

```
def imagesform(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            for i in form['image']:
                Image(image=i).save()

    form = AddImageForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'members/imagesform.html', context)
```

Also, make you sure you add the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` tag.